# How to terminate active socket connections properly in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using a socket connection as a client, with `spring-integration-ip`:

```
@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() throws Exception {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean f = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    f.setType("client");
    f.setHost(host);
    f.setPort(port);
    ...
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "clientChannel")
public TcpOutboundGateway outboundGatewasy(AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory) throws Exception {
    TcpOutboundGateway g = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    g.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    g.setRequiresReply(true);
    return gate;
}
```

Now I could inject `@Autowired TcpOutboundGateway gate`. But there is no method like `.beforeShutdown()` or `getActiveConnections()`.

So, how can I retrieve the active socket connections when the application is shut down?

Comment: Do you want to close the connections before the app shut down?

Comment: I want, if active connections, delay the shutdown for a specific time. Then close the connections before the app shuts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections are managed by the connection factory, not the gateway.

Autowire the connection factory instead, and use `getOpenConnectionIds()`.

Use `closeConnection(String connectionId)` to close a connection.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44760185Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So44760185Application.class, args);
        MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("clientChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        try {
            channel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
            System.err.println("Expected ConnectException");
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            if (!(e.getCause().getCause() instanceof ConnectException)) {
                throw e;
            }
            System.out.println("good1");
        }

        context.getBean(ShuttingDownAdvice.class).shuttingDown = true;

        try {
            channel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
            System.err.println("Expected shutting down exception");
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            if (!(e.getCause().getMessage().equals("No new connections allowed"))) {
                throw e;
            }
            System.out.println("good2");
        }
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public static TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean connectionFactoryBean() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean f = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        f.setType("client");
        f.setHost("localhost");
        f.setPort(1234);
        return f;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "clientChannel")
    public TcpOutboundGateway outboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory) throws Exception {
        TcpOutboundGateway g = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        g.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        g.setRequiresReply(true);
        g.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(advice()));
        return g;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShuttingDownAdvice advice() {
        return new ShuttingDownAdvice();
    }

    public static class ShuttingDownAdvice extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

        private volatile boolean shuttingDown;

        @Override
        protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
            if (this.shuttingDown) {
                throw new RuntimeException("No new connections allowed");
            }
            return callback.execute();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can I also tell the `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` to reject any "open socket" requests while I'm waiting a specific time until I shut down the currently pending connections?

Comment: No, but you can add a [custom advice to the outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#custom-advice) to do that. It's a bit tricky to do that with java config because the advice chain goes on the `ConsumerEndpoint` created by the `@ServiceActivator` annotation; you can use a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` `@Bean` instead.

Comment: You could not give an example on a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` for this purpose? That's really difficult to understand...

Comment: My mistake; the advice chain is applied directly to the outbound gateway, so using `@ServiceActivator` is ok. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect. One last question: is it necessary to create the `Advice` as a `@Bean`? Or could I just create a `g.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(new ShuttingDownAdvice()));`?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `@Bean` - I did that so that I could get a reference to it later, to set the boolean to start rejecting new requests. If it's not a bean you'll need some other technique to do that.